# Algorithm to choose a transparent color for GIF

Tags: algorithm, unique, gif

I have a bunch (up to 255) of colors (of the total 256^3 possible values) and for compression purposes I want to think up some another color, that isn't among them.

For example, I have such a small color table: `[0,0,0]`, `[1,42,69]` -- any one of the remaining 256^3-2 colors would be fine -- no matter whether it is `[0,0,7]` or `[6,6,6]`.

Can someone provide me with an easy and efficient algorithm to find another color?

**UPD:** bad ideas are also welcome.

Comment: This sounds like a test, lol.

Comment: Generate random colors until you get one not in the table? Absent problems with the random source, the expected number of retries is very small.

Comment: @durbnpoisn, no, I just make own library in Ruby, and while asking myself and SO, already have nice idea, but would like to see other thoughts.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, true about low collision probability, but RND function usage can be slow.

Comment: BUT probably there is such an iterative function that can pseudorandomly walk from [0,0,0] through all 256^3. Or even not through all 256^3 but at least through 256 before looping. YES! smth simple found be fine like [R,G,B]+=[+1,-1,0]

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a hash table of all known colors, and put your colors into it.
2. Make an algorithm that takes a color, and produces its "successor" by incrementing the lowest byte, and continuing with the increment into higher-order bytes when there is a carry.
3. Start at `[0,0,0]` and check it against the hash table from step 1.
4. Loop until you find the first gap.

This algorithm is linear in the number of colors.

Comment: Right.  Something like "base 256" where when the highest number in blue is reached, it rolls over green to 1, and resets blue to 0. And so on.  Sooner or later your bound to find one that's not used.  At worst, you'll have to count up to 16.7 million.  Which shouldn't be that hard anyway.

Comment: @durbnpoisn No, at most you would have to count 256, because 256-th number is not going to be in your hash table.

Comment: right.  That's the highest number of colors to compare against.  But if you actually kept counting and the final result is 256,256,256, you'll have to have counted 16.7 million numbers.

Comment: @durbnpoisn No, you are not just counting. You stop when the hash table **does not** have the current color. This could happen right away if there's no `[0,0,0]` or in 5 steps if there's no `[0,0,5]` among the original colors, or in 256 steps if all colors are of the format `[0,0,<some-number>]` (that's the worst case). You never increment past `[0,1,0]`.

Comment: The easiest way to increment is to combine all 3 colors into a single 24-bit integer, then just increment normally.

Answer (score 2):

Since now we have two answers, I would like to post my own.

We don't want any color in existing color table to become transparent. That is why I stated, that color table can be maximum of **255** colors long.
Because of this there would be at least one Red (or Green or Blue, whatever) channel value left unused. So we don't have to use 256^3 large table of flags -- 256 (bits for memory or bytes for speed) would be enough.

Comment: This is brilliant. Since backgrounds are often light colored, and yellow is the lightest, I'd suggest using red=255, green=255, and the highest missing blue as your transparent color.

Answer (score 1):

Walk through your image, counting the number of times each of the 256 possible pixel values occurs. Use `std::min_element` (for one possibility) to find the smallest count, and use that color number. If you're really talking about 256 possible color values, that's about it.

If you really have 24 bits per pixel, then you probably want to use a sparse representation for the counts, since (for any reasonable size of picture) many of them will inevitably be zero (you'd need roughly a 16-megapixel picture to even theoretically use all the possible colors). OTOH, on a modern computer, even using the few dozen megabytes (or so) necessary for a dense representation of the count may be worthwhile--it'll probably make your processing faster (no hash codes to compute) and still little enough memory usage that the reduction in processing time is worth it.